# IronPython & WPF: Binding a checkbox's IsChecked property to a class member variable

Tags: python, wpf, visual-studio-2010, binding, ironpython

I've seen many similar questions on how to get data binding working with a checkbox, but **all** of the examples I've seen are in C# and I can't seem to make the leap to convert it to IronPython. I have a checkbox defined in a window thusly:

```
<Window xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Name="Test" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" mc:Ignorable="d">
    <DockPanel>     
        <CheckBox Name="bindtest" IsChecked="{Binding Path=o1checked, Mode=OneWay}"></CheckBox>
        <Button Content="Toggle" Name="Toggle" Padding="5"></Button>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

And I want its IsChecked value to automatically update when `self.o1checked` is toggled in the following class:

```
class MaikoCu64(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.o1checked = False
        ui.win['Button']['Toggle'].Click += self.Toggle_OnClick

    def Toggle_OnClick(self, sender, event):
        self.o1checked = not self.o1checked
```

(That `ui` object is a class that has the xaml loaded into it as a dictonary of ui controls. See [here](http://www.ironpython.info/index.php/XAML_GUI_Events_Example))

So how do I make this happen? After hours of reading through the MSDN binding documentation (also all in C#) I've tried adding this:

```
import System
myBinding = System.Windows.Data.Binding("o1checked")
myBinding.Source = self
myBinding.Mode = System.Windows.Data.BindingMode.OneWay
ui.win['CheckBox']['bindtest'].SetBinding(System.Windows.Controls.CheckBox.IsCheckedProperty, myBinding)
```

It doesn't work, but it seems like it makes at least some sense. Am I on the right track?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The property should use INotifyPropertyChanged interface. See my [blog](http://gui-at.blogspot.com/2009/11/inotifypropertychanged-in-ironpython.html) for an example how to implement it in IronPython.

Also note there is a Silverlight [bug](http://ironpython.codeplex.com/workitem/28823) in .NET or IronPython causing an error when anything else than string should be propagated back into viewmodel.

Comment: Ok, this took me all week and many attempts to digest/understand/implement/test, but I finally have something similar to this working, though I am using the `__setattr__` method you mentioned in your blog for now. Thanks for posting it! Once I iron out my bugs I'll post some of my code to show how I did it. Mainly it involves inheriting from the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface and calling `self._OnPropertyChanged` inside `__setattr__` whenever i need to tell the gui binding to update its bound target from source.

Comment: Well, what you do in `__setter__` is exactly what the `@notify_property` decorator does. If you post your code, I can try to fix it.